# Зафиксировать значение при достижении отметки времени

Tags: excel, vba

В ячейке А1 у меня счетчик времени (получает значение из обновляемого источника), например 0:03:30 - 3 минуты 30 секунд, тикает вверх по одной секунде.

В ячейке А2 - самообновляемый коэффициент, тоже из другого источника.

Задача - в ячейке А3 сохранить значение А2, когда А1 равен 0:05:00. Когда время пойдет дальше - значение в А3 должно сохраниться и не меняться. То есть А2 будет дальше обновляться, а А3 - нет.

Я пробую в А3 написать формулу:

```
=ЕСЛИ(А1 = 0:05:00;$A$2;$A$2)
```

при этом варианте мое значение в А3 продолжает обновляться, что мне не надо, если попробовать

```
=ЕСЛИ(А1 = 0:05:00;$A$2;)
```

то на следующую секунду после пятой минуты А3 возвращает 0, а хочу сохранить то, что было.

Comment: Нужно сослаться на саму себя, а это зацикливание. Макросы можно применять?

Comment: Да, конечно можно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ячейка должна сослаться сама на себя, а это - циклические вычисления, которые недопустимы при обычной работе в *Excel*.

Выход есть. Даже два. Начнем с правильного.

В модуль нужного листа записать код, который отслеживает события листа (изменение ячейки А1).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'    If Range("A3").Value <> "" Then Exit Sub '

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = 5 / 1440 Then Range("A3").Value = Range("A2").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Можно раскомментировать строку, если перед записью ячейка *А3* пустая

---

Второй вариант не очень правильный, но имеет право на жизнь.

Для всяческих точных вычислений (например, в геодезии) *Excel*  имеет неплохой инструмент - итеративные вычисления. Это по сути разрешение зацикливания вычислений заданное количество раз. Например, задали коэффициент, применили пересчитанный уточненный коэффициент, пересчитали еще раз, еще... и получили значение нужной точности.

Этот хороший инструмент можно использовать не по прямому назначению - разрешить циклические вычисления для сохранения значения.

`Файл-параметры-Формулы`, разрешить циклические вычисления, число итераций достаточно 1.

Формула в *А3*

```
=ЕСЛИ(A1=5/1440;A2;A3)
```

Итеративные вычисления если и применять, то только с полным осознанием возможных негативных последствий.

== Можно легко пропустить ошибку, вызванную зацикливанием вычислений там, где это не предусмотрено.

== Пример еще одного нежданчика.

Открыта книга с разрешенными итерациями. Открываем другую книгу. В ней итерации отключены. Были отключены! Теперь разрешены. И если со второй книгой поработали, сохранили ее (отключить итерации, конечно же, забыли), то при следующем открытии циклические вычисления в ней уже разрешены.

Comment: По поводу итераций. Чем эта включенная опция может помешать, если я не собираюсь использовать циклические, ссылающиеся сами на себя формулы?

Comment: Ничем, если учитывать указанные моменты. Пример: при работе с книгой, в которой много зависимостей, при записи очередной формулы было вызвано зацикливание вычислений. Цикл шел через 8 формул (в 1 ссылка на 2, во второй - на 3,... в 8 - на 1). При включенных итеративных это прошло бы незаметно и в итоге - неправильные расчеты.  Еще - самопроизвольное изменение настройки итераций в книгах, которые открываются не первыми (т.е. разрешение/запрет циклических вычислений по настройке в первой открытой книге).